# Regular Expression removing <![CDATA[

Tags: python, html, regex, cdata

I have this regular expression:

```
</title>[\s]*<description[^>]*>(.*?)<img
```

which takes the string:

```
<title>Insane price of last Ford Falcon V8s</title>
        <description><![CDATA[FORD dealers are charging a staggering $30,000 more than the recommended retail price — up from $60,000 to $90,000 — for the final Falcon V8 sedans as buyers try to secure a future classic.<img alt="" border="0" src="https://pixel.wp.com/b.gif?host=www.couriermail.com.au&#038;blog=87782261&#038;post=1205849&#038;subd=couriermailatnewscorpau&#038;ref=&#038;feed=1" width="1" height="1" />]]></description>
```

how can i edit this regular expression to also remove `<![CDATA[`

Answer (score -1):

Regular expressions are really mighty tool. This includes a high risk of getting bugs into your code, especially when you do not know how to handle them exactly (it seems this is the case here).

You should always go with Python's built-in string class first and *only* use RegEx, if it is necessary.

If you have your string `my_str`, then the following code replaces a substring in `my_str`:

```
my_str = "hello world"
my_str.replace("lo", "")
>>> "hel world"
```

`str.replace` searches for a "lo" in this case and replaces it with "" (nothing, thus deleting it). Of course you can alter this values as you like.

Take a look at [Python's documention for Strings](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html).